# http-server run in the background

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, server, httpserver

I installed npm http-server and it is working great sharing my directory to which I want all local PCs to have access. But can I make it running in the background? I am running it through cmd. I tried the following:

```
http-server . &
```

and after installing npm forever

```
forever start -c http-server
```

None of them is working for me. It is Windows server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all locate your http-server by running the following command:

   ```
   which http-server
   ```

   You should get something like this:

   > `/usr/bin/http-server`
2. Then `cd` to the directory you want to serve files from and execute:

   ```
   forever start /usr/bin/http-server -p 80 -d false
   ```

Comment: But "$" is not recognized by cmd.

Comment: don't copy with $, copy this    which http-server      and paste into your terminal and run :)

Comment: Yes, 'which' is not recognized also.

Comment: Yes and in question I mentioned that this is Windows server.

Comment: use where if you're using Windows, sorry my bad I didn't read work "Windows".

Comment: Still not working as expected. It is generating me some path(where command) in which there is this http-server file but when I start it it is not sharing the directory.

Comment: like dir <Folder Name> /AD /s

Comment: Generated file http-server is located in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm and the directory I want to share is in D:\ . Anyway I am not sure how it should work

Comment: this work for me, but client get `Access to ***** was denied` . if i delete -d false, client can access server, but it can access all files in root dir `/`. finally i use `forever start /usr/bin/http-server -p 80 /Users/user/webdir
` and it works